# Null Conditional Operator Only Evaluates Once

Tags: c#

I was reading about the Null Conditional operator introduced in C# 6.0 but I'm not understanding it fully.

From https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6

```
int? first = customers?[0].Orders.Count();
```

This example is essentially equivalent to:

```
int? first = (customers != null) ? customers[0].Orders.Count() : null;
```

**Except that customers is only evaluated once.**

Can someone elaborate on the 'evaluated once' verse (I'm assuming) evaluated twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better equivalency to your first statement

```
var temp = customers;
int? first;
if(temp != null)
{
    first = temp[0].Orders.Count();
}
else
{
    first = null;
}
```

The variable `customers` is only "touched" once. This is more significant when `customers` is a property that does some action in the `get` or is a function.

```
private int accessCount = 0;
private Customers[] _customers;
private Customers[] customers 
{
    get
    {
        accessCount++;
        return _customers;
    }
    set
    {
        _customers = value;
    }
}
```

In your 2nd example the `customers` property would have to be "touched" twice, once for the null check once for the indexer, giving `accessCount` a value of `2`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It means the program accesses `customers` only once. In the second example, `customers` is accessed twice, first for the null check and second for the `Orders` property if it's non-null.

In the new feature, `customers` will be accessed only once, and if it's non-null, it won't be accessed again (e.g. it won't be possible it to become null if something modifies the field) and the already-accessed object will be used.